# Pathway mediates nitroglycerin-induced relief from angina pectoris

Tags: biochemistry, homework

what kind of Pathway mediates nitroglycerin-induced relief from angina pectoris,please provide some idea...

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Can you please show what you have done so far to find an answer?

Comment: @Chris I missed my class so I really had no idea how to approach this question I did some literature search but it was confusing ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of nitroglycerin on the cardiac tissue is similar to nitric oxide (NO),  which forms in the endothelium of blood vessels from arginin metabolism products.

So, the general scheme can look like this:

R-NO<sub>2</sub> is converted to R-NO outside of the cell (glutathion-SH-dependent reaction). NO is lipophilic and rapidly penetrates into the cell where it activates guanylate cyclase. From this moment you can see the resulting influence on myosin and actin on this picture:

[image: muscle relaxation NO related]